# Discord.js Embed Title and Thumbnail not being set

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I have gotten all of my embeds to work, but when I try to write one with a variable instead of just giving it a string, it creates a blank embed in Discord. Are there any certain permissions that may be preventing the bot from using API information in an embed?

```
command(client, ['s', 'S'], (message) => {
    const arg = message.content.slice(prefix.length + "s".length).trim()
    var title = ""
    var img = ""
    
    imdb.searchMovies(arg, movies => {
        title = movies[0].title
        console.log(title)
        img = movies[0].primaryPhoto
        console.log(img)
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    })

    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(title)
    .setThumbnail(img)

    message.channel.send(embed)
})
```

Comment: `"s".length` <= wut?

Comment: it's not an issue with the argument handler. the "s".length is there to remove the "?s" of every command and be left with the argument. "?s example" -> "example"

Comment: `"s".length` resolves to a number `1`.  I'm pointing out that you are creating a string to access the length property that will always be 1, instead of just using the value of `1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`imbd.searchMovies` is not awaitable, so all the code after will run before the request is completed.

```
   imdb.searchMovies(arg, movies => {
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
    .setTitle(movies[0].title)
    .setThumbnail(movies[0].primaryPhoto)
    message.channel.send(embed)
    }, error => {
        console.log(error)
    })
```